# importing PIL into a rosnode

Tags: ros, python, rospy, osx, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I have the line

"from PIL import Image"

in a node, I get the following error when running my node via rosrun

"ImportError: No module named PIL"

of course, PIL is installed in

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL

but is not an ROS library.  How can I change my manifest.xml to find PIL?  If I understand correctly, rosrun clobbers my existing PYTHONPATH (when running python I can import PIL just fine).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9804/importing-pil-into-a-rosnode/) by [jrieffel](https://answers.ros.org/users/432/jrieffel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2011-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved it by explicitly putting PIL in my .bashrc's PYTHONPATH

oddly, however, python from the command line runs python 2.6.6, but rosrun on a python node somehow invokes python 2.6.1

---

Originally posted by [jrieffel](https://answers.ros.org/users/432/jrieffel/) with karma: 39 on 2011-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0